# create table in DB from excel data in sheet

Tags: mysql, excel, odbc

I need help creating table in DB through Excel.

User has table in excel sheet, which has not exact count of columns. User can add or reduce columns and of course add or reduce rows too.
I need a script for example for ODBC Microsoft Query which choose all table range in excel sheet and create table with this data in DB (MySQL). 
It has to work on a one click not manually.

Thank you

Comment: I am trying lot of "solution" but it does not work fine. The best solution was add plugin "MySQL for Excel" into Excel, but it works only manualy and when I record macro for it, it does not work.. I am trying "Insert2DBMySQL" function, which I saw on Stackoverflow in topic "How to insert data from an excel sheet into a database table?", but it does not work too .. I'm trying find solution already 3 days and this my post was last chance for result, it is possible or not .. Maybe I'll just be able to say that by using ODBC Microsoft Query is it not possible or just lead me on the right path.

Comment: Access has very simple way as export table into database through Database ODBC. Is similar way in Excel? Any Idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is solution for me. It's not exactly what I wanted, but it's enough for me now. After some modifications, it works on MySQL.
[tomaslind.net - export data excel to sql server](http://tomaslind.net/2013/12/26/export-data-excel-to-sql-server/)